# In The Last Battle, what made Rishda Tarkaan Tash's "lawful prey"?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-narnia

In [Chapter 12](https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/lewiscs-lastbattle/lewiscs-lastbattle-00-h.html#chap12) King Tirian was able to force his combatant Rishda Tarkaan into the stable, forcing Rishda to face Carlomene's god Tash.

> But immediately, from behind Tash, strong and calm as the summer sea, a voice said:
>
> **"Begone, Monster, and take your lawful prey to your own place: in the name of Aslan and Aslan's great Father, the Emperor-over-sea."**
>
> The hideous creature vanished, with the Tarkaan still under its arm. And Tirian turned to see who had spoken. And what he saw then set his heart beating as it had never beaten in any fight.
>
> Seven Kings and Queens stood before him, all with crowns on their heads and all in glittering clothes, but the Kings wore fine mail as well and had their swords drawn in their hands. (snip)

**The question**: What made Rishda Tarkaan Tash's "lawful prey"?  An answer based on either 1) CSL's writings, interview, letters, and/or 2) comparison with Christian theology is welcomed.

The answer seems to need explanation deriving from several factors:

- The ontological status of Tash: what creature is it?
- How did Tash became god to the Calormenes?
- What kind of "crimes" qualify someone, more specifically Rishda, to be Tash's lawful prey?
- How (in light of the "Begone" sentence) did Aslan seem to have authority over Tash?

Comment: I always presumed it went something like this: Rishda is a Calormene --> Tash is the (angry, violent, blood-hungry-but-brutally fair) Calormene god --> Rishda blasphemed against Tash --> Tash smote the blasphemer. Or else Tash is just an allegory of the Judeo-Christian devil and is representative of the devil dragging the sinners/blasphemers/pagans to their horrific end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think Tash's lawful prey was particular to anything Christian, per se.

Rishda had been working with Shift (the ape) to proffer that Aslan had returned. In reality, Shift had sewn a lion's skin on Puzzle the donkey and had fooled the other creatures. This was, in fact, a way for the Calormenes (of which Rishda was one) to begin to move resources into Narnia and gradually take over from the Narnian monarch (Tirian). The catch was that the Calormenes didn't believe in Aslan, but Tash. When this comes into conflict with the idea that they were acting on Aslan's behalf, while still worshiping Tash, they declare that Aslan and Tash are really the same being, which leads to the even more nonsensical "Tashlan". In the meantime, there are reports of the real Tash walking around Narnia's forests.

When things start hitting the fan, Rishda reverts to just worshipping Tash. Shift is tossed into the stable where "Tashlan" has supposedly been (Puzzle had long since left), and is promptly eaten by the real Tash. When Tirian eventually forces Rishda into the shed, Rishda is astonished to find the real Tash there. Just before the quoted scene, Tash confronts Rishda

> Thou hast called me into Narnia, Rishda Tarkaan. Here I am. What hast thou to say?

The implication of his being "lawful prey" is that Rishda is a worshiper of Tash, and therefore belongs to Tash of his own free will (albeit probably not in the way Rishda imagined). As such, when Peter tells Tash to leave, he has no basis to tell Tash to leave Rishda (not that he would want to). In other words, Rishda's end with Tash is a simple comeuppance for a major antagonist.

Tash is probably based on an amalgamation of other ideas. For instance, [Kali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali) has four arms and behaves similar to Tash. Many other deities have animal heads ([Moloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moloch), for example, was a common one in Jewish history/Old Testament).

Comment: So what the voice (King Peter or one of the 7) means is that since the stable is in Narnian territory, Tash and the Carlomen people don't belong there.  So Tash should take its Carlomen subject out of Narnia by the authority of the Lord of Narnia, which is Aslan?  That still leaves something unexplained about Tash and Emeth, but your answer has fully addressed the question about why Rishda is Tash's lawful prey, so I'll ask another question.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, Emeth is really another topic entirely